# DataFrame with repeated indexes - how do I count the frequency of each index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like so:

```
    ages
0    94.0
0    94.0
0    94.0
1    30.0
1    30.0
2    64.0
2    64.0
2    64.0
3    57.0
3    57.0
3    57.0
```

You can see that the indexes are repeated multiple times for some indexes.
I want to count the frequency of each index. How can I do this?

Expected output would be an array like so:

```
# 3 because 0 repeats 3 times, 2 because 1 repeats 2 times, 3 because 2 repeats 3 times, and 3 because 3 repeats 3 times.
array([3, 2, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html) on index

```py
out = df.index.value_counts().sort_index().to_numpy()
# or
out = df.index.value_counts(sort=False).to_numpy()
```

NOTE: `sort_index()` makes the output be always ascending order. `sort=False` keeps the order of value's first appearance.

```
print(out)

[3 2 3 3]
```